# GradReverseLayer :NotImplementedError: You must implement the backward function for custom autograd.Function

Tags: pytorch, cross-domain

I'm recently in a domain adaptation program which involves using gradreverselayer.

This is what I'm using.

```js
class GradReverse(Function):
    def forward(ctx, x, alpha):
        ctx.alpha = alpha

        return x

    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        output = grad_output.neg() * ctx.alpha

        return output, None
```

It seems there's nothing wrong with it.

However, when I run my code, it raised this error.

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 125, in <module>
    class_criterion, domain_criterion,  optimizer, trainloader1, valloader, trainloader2, testloader2)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/TRANSFER/Train.py", line 325, in train_original
    src_domain_loss.backward(retain_graph=True) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 245, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 147, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 89, in apply
    return self._forward_cls.backward(self, *args)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/function.py", line 201, in backward
    raise NotImplementedError("You must implement the backward function for custom"
NotImplementedError: You must implement the backward function for custom autograd.Function.
```

I can't figure it out. So I add

```js
src_domain_loss=torch.tensor(src_domain_loss, requires_grad=True)
```

And there's no warning.

Howerver, when I check my net's grad, it's like this:

```js
-->name: domain_classifier.c_fc1.weight -->grad_requirs: True -->grad_value: None
-->name: domain_classifier.c_fc1.bias -->grad_requirs: True -->grad_value: None
-->name: domain_classifier.c_fc2.weight -->grad_requirs: True -->grad_value: None
-->name: domain_classifier.c_fc2.bias -->grad_requirs: True -->grad_value: None
```

And once I remove the gradreverselayer, it works well. No warning, and the grad is fine.

It really bothers me. I wish someone could help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved the problem. It's really a stupid mistake.
The problem lies on '@staticmethod'!
The GradReverseLayer should be like:

```html
class GradReverse(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, x, alpha, **kwargs:None):
        ctx.alpha = alpha

        return x.view_as(x)
    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        output = grad_output * -ctx.alpha
      
        return output, None
```

I always think it's just a note! And I delete it every time!

But I still don't know why

```html
src_domain_loss=torch.tensor(src_domain_loss, requires_grad=True)
```

this would lead to zero grad in backward process. Does anybody have some ideas? It will be nice if we can discuss about it lol.